# Como puedo convertir el array de bytes en un archivo pdf y que se muestre en el navegador el pdf, con .Net

Tags: c#, array, pdf

Tengo el siguiente código que contiene un array de bytes perteneciente a un archivo pdf, y quiero que ese array se convierte en un archivo pdf que se muestre por navegador estoy usando un metodo de descarga de archivos este es mi codigo:

```
LoginEShopNet loginEShopNet = GetCurrentURL(_httpContextAccessor);
UserResponse Usuariodto = _consultasEntity.ControlAcceso(loginEShopNet.Usuario, loginEShopNet.Password, loginEShopNet.Plataforma);


string RutaDocumentoOracle = _consultasEntity.ObtenerDocumentPathBBDD(new common.Infrastructure.Oracle.dto.Document(true, loginEShopNet.Poliza, true, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty));

string startPath = "//lalfs/oracle/docu_doc/";
string pathglobal = "";
if (RutaDocumentoOracle.Length > 1)
{
    pathglobal = startPath + getRealPath(RutaDocumentoOracle);
}

#region Open and Return Document
try
{
     #region Open and Return Document
     FileStream fs = null;
     try
     {
         fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(pathglobal);
         byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
         fs.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
         return bytes;
     }
     finally
     {
         if (fs != null)
         {
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
         }
     }
     #endregion
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     return null;
 }
```

Comment: como implementas el envio del pdf al navegador?

Comment: es un desarrollo web con asp.net ? o es asp.net mvc, digo porque mencionas que se debe enviar al browser

Comment: El archivo llega como una URL y se obtienen los datos a partir, de un metodo de separacion y cuando se forma el pdf a partir de la URL, deberia de visualizarse en el navegador, Actualmente es un servicio API